# Android Packaging Error: Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

Tags: android, installation

I am new to Android and trying to install  Eclipse-indigo i am having windows 7 and followed the steps for installation ,but when i  have started creating the project and try to run it gives me the error

Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13        Android Packaging Problem. Whwn i clean it the red cross goes out but when i run it again shows mw this.

i dont get what could be the problem ,please help out.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this things, It should be help for you

Head over to Help -> Install New Software. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. press "alt+ctrl+del" -> click on "start task manager"-> select process tab and within that select the adb.exe and click on end process.
2. close eclipse application
3. search for .android folder in your computer and delete that folder.
   [steps to search for folder click on this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/find-file-folder#1TC=windows-7)
4. restart your eclipse. create new avd and enjoy your coding... :)